# When changing values in the database why does this not affect the view?

Tags: 7, views

edit: How could i use Views bulk operations for the change of a field's value? Instead of directly editing mysql?
I have a content type, f.e  mycontentype, which has titles, like:

```
Title - library1
another title - library1
yet another title - library1
```

so i went in the db and with a MySQL command, i updated all titles to

```
Title
another title
yet another title
```

My issue here is that in a view, i have as a field, the

Content: mycontenttype

which i have set to the formatter as title link.

This brinks as the title the old title  Title - library1, but when this link is clicked, we go the the node  where the title is shown correctly.

if in the formatter i choose full content, i get again all data updated, including the correct title.

Of course i have cleared all caches, i have run update.php,

any ideas?

Comment: For one, its not good to edit the database directly. There are plenty of triggers that happen when you save an entity in the UI/code through the framework. Two, it could be cached by that view or you did not edit any possible revision table as well. The view result could also be cached.

Comment: how could i remove all cached content from the views? "Two, it could be cached by that view" and "The view result could also be cached"? i used the TRUNCATE with all cache named tables, but i get no different behavior.. i am afraid i have to work on mysql directly, since i need to remove a field's data that was inserted wrong, in a batch process. f.e. i have many nodes, which have a certain value in a field, and i must set this value to none, for all nodes that have the same error value...

Comment: Did u edit the node to check that the field value did indeed change?

Comment: Yes, as per @Kevin's comment look at the revision table as well.